# Blender Bevel can not bevel a simple all-quad geometry!

Tags: modifiers, bevel

[image]

Bevel modifier has no problem giving a beautiful result for a mesh with a bunch of N-gons (The outer mesh) but cannot properly bevel a simple all-quad mesh (The inner mesh)?!

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. Turn out all I have to do is to flip normal of faces at the area with the problem. 
[image]